# What does 'pedigree information' mean?

Tags: genetics

[This paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10682-013-9639-x) uses Pied Flycatcher as a study species. For the population of Pied Flycatchers they studied, 'pedigree information' was available. What exactly does this 'pedigree information' mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that they [recorded family information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedigree_chart) for the traits that they were investigating in the paper, i.e., they had plumage characteristics for siblings or parent-offspring pairs. Look for this phrase in the paper: "phenotypic data usually available for one or two generations, mostly from parent-offspring pairs or siblings."